# Sort query for dynamic array in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query

I have a collection in MongoDB like below format. Now i want to know how to apply sorting. Please find example of collection below,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e5e140f113a6c3970eef3bb"),
    "FormId" : "5cd3a0a0cb20953208fcb549",
    "FieldsDatas" : [         
        {
            "FieldId" : "4fbcef5b-d60a-4908-a037-5ff085b70709",
            "Value" : [ 
                "202003031"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "FieldId" : "708e1baf-fcd0-45fa-b1de-27f34391c35c",
            "Value" : [ 
                "202003031"
            ]
        },
        {
            "FieldId" : "0b563a80-2b0a-4803-ad7f-652a381e134c",
            "Value" : [ 
                "New Source", 
                "Endpoint"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "FieldId" : "15355b82-4fae-4c09-acb4-13f95e8c2d4e",
            "Value" : [ 
                "2020-03-03 13:51:17"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "FieldId" : "1e32a283-34a9-4a7b-b851-3e5ac7f93d2c",
            "Value" : [ 
                "tets"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e5e1c89113a6c3970eef3bc"),
    "FormId" : "5cd3a0a0cb20953208fcb549"
    "FieldsDatas" : [         
        {
            "FieldId" : "708e1baf-fcd0-45fa-b1de-27f34391c35c",
            "Value" : [ 
                "202003032"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "FieldId" : "0eca0881-a69b-4db3-b8b1-d74b0a16d4ef",
            "Value" : [ 
                "20200303_2@mail.com"
            ]
        },
        {
            "FieldId" : "2da67714-aaf3-433d-9a86-1b48c75470ec",
            "Value" : [ 
                "mani lj"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "FieldId" : "a0b26aac-cad0-4c5e-83b4-9a01ac4ce97a",
            "Value" : []
        }, 
        {
            "FieldId" : "15355b82-4fae-4c09-acb4-13f95e8c2d4e",
            "Value" : [ 
                "2020-03-03 14:29:23"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For above collection i have date inside the array of objects called `FieldsDatas` where `"FieldId": "15355b82-4fae-4c09-acb4-13f95e8c2d4e"` in that same `"Value"` array has `datetime`. I want to sort the result based in this `datetime`.

I have a filter query. How to add sort query for above scenario?

```
db.getCollection('Collection').find({ 
    "$and":[
        { 
           FieldsDatas: {
              $elemMatch:{
                  FieldId:'955c9843-1535-4df8-a1c4-09430ac9f6ba',
                  Value: { $ne: ["Contact"] }
              }
           }
        }
     ]
})
.limit(5)
.skip(30);
```

Anyone please help me to add sorting for this query like above datetime field.

Any possibilities to achieve this by Stored procedure or functions. Please let me know.

Thanks in advance,
Mani

Comment: Do you expect to handle any date time format?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to sort by DateTime which is inside "FieldsDatas" -> "Value" by FieldID. That's all

Comment: That has many formats and even strings too.

Comment: yes. Actually that was date string so i have to convert to DateTime and do sort in the Query itself